# Fancybox - Images are not resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

Fancybox works fine on IE9 but when I try to use it on Firefox it show small image.

Please help.

[**Here is the link.**](http://www.techcentiveservices.com/services/sred/sred-time-tracking/)

Thanks,
Manpreet

Answer (score 0):

you should use images in links:

```
<a href="original-url"><img src="small-url" /></a>
```

or

```
<a href="original-url"><img width="100" height="100" src="original-url" /></a>
```